# Apache Error log: Log only for part of server

Tags: php, apache, error-handling, debian, vps

I'm running Debian on a VPS server, and have both the development and production code and database on the same server.

Is it possible to get the server to log only the errors for the development part of the server, and not the production. Right now, there are so many errors being logged from the production side, which makes it hard to get to the development errors.

Comment: you can change log settings per directory or per file

Comment: I would vote for 2 log locations rather then no logging for production, or do you really want to lose hundreds of clients in some production-hickup, without any knowledge after the fact what actually happened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although this really belongs on serverfault.com:

**You should definitely always log all errors.**

If you host for example 2 domains on your server, example.com and test.example.com you can specify for each virtual host where you want to store the logs.

On apache your virtual hosts could look like:

```
<VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80>
    // some configuration stuff
    ServerName     example.com
    // some more configuration stuff
    CustomLog      /var/log/httpd/example.com-access_log combined
    ErrorLog       /var/log/httpd/example.com-error_log
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80>
    // some configuration stuff
    ServerName     test.example.com
    // some more configuration stuff
    CustomLog      /var/log/httpd/test.example.com-access_log combined
    ErrorLog       /var/log/httpd/test.example.com-error_log
</VirtualHost>
```

So you can easily distinguish log information for `test.example.com` from  `example.com`.